# Python Twilio Message blocked (Error - 30004)

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I tried to create a python app which sends a sms notification using twilio. When I try to send a message using the twilio client I get (in the Twilio Debugger):

```
Error - 30004

Message Delivery - Message blocked

Possible Causes

The destination number you are trying to reach is blocked from receiving this message (ex. due to blacklisting).
```

I did the steps, got number, got token, what should I do to resolve the error?

Comment: @roganjosh well, yes. But i did the steps and can't really see what to do to resolve the issue... how to unblock?

Comment: At a guess did you have prototype code that might have blasted them with API calls while setting this up?

Comment: @roganjosh no just sent the first message ...

Comment: Is this a new, trial account? Have you [verified the number you are sending to in your Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/verified)?

Comment: @philnash yes, i had. However, i tried a different number and it just worked.

Comment: Ah, cool. Glad to hear it's working now :)

Comment: Yup, It is working with different number as first number has blocked this twilio number :(

Answer (score 1):

It depends from number to number. It could be block as promotional message. I faced this issue while sending SMS to Indian number.

> Limitations sending SMS messages to Indian mobile devices
>
> SMS messages entering into India are categorized as “Transactional” or “Promotional” and may result as an "Error - 30004".
>
> By default, all SMS messages sent from Twilio phone numbers are categorized as “Promotional” and are subject to the following limitations:

They cannot be sent to any phone number in India’s Do Not Call Registry

> If you’ve been having trouble sending SMS messages to an Indian number, see if that number is registered on the [National Do Not Call Registry](http://www.nccptrai.gov.in/nccpregistry/search.misc).
>
> If the owner of the phone number wishes to start receiving SMS messages from Twilio, they can update the DNC settings by following the instructions [on this website](http://www.nccptrai.gov.in/nccpregistry/).

More details : https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134167-Limitations-sending-SMS-messages-to-Indian-mobile-devices