# Twilio is not sending SMS to some Indian numbers

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to send sms with twilio which is working fine with some number but I'm getting "Error - 30004" for few Indian numbers.

When I do some research I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46255734/python-twilio-message-blocked-error-30004)

But as the answer is not accepted I'm not sure about the reason

Even if that is the reason can we change our SMS category of twilio from default "Promotional" to any which SMS can be received by others.

Comment: The answer of the link you shared is not the solution. It explain about the reason. And there is nothing can be done about this. As per the Govt rules SMSs sent via Twilio are considered as promotional. That category can not be changed. Twilio can guarantee the delivery of SMS if you send SMS via preregistered Twilio SenderID for India. You can get more details at https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines/in

Comment: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID